# Change android chip icon position

Tags: android, material-design, android-chips

I have added a few chips in my app. The default chip have tick icon when you select it like this. [image]

I want to change the icon position to the bottom. Like this. 
[image]

There is no property to change the icon position. How can I achieve this result.

Comment: Is it mandatory to use material chips to achieve these kind of UI results?
I think you can do it in any other ways.

Comment: Yes I achieved this result with the help of layer-list but wanted to do it with the help of chips

Comment: You can't do it with a Chip.You can use an iconStart or an iconEnd.

Comment: Okay then use custom layout for your chip view, and inflate it when you are adding your chip. Use layer-list background to which one is selected or not. Will these procedure serve your purposes?@kartooskhan

Answer (score 1):

use this property to change chip icon position:

```
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set `android:layoutDirection="rtl"` or the opposite of your current direction to put the icon on the right.

For more: https://material.io/design/usability/bidirectionality.html

Answer (score 0):

Start icon

`app:chipIconVisible` — visibility of the chip icon.
`app:chipIcon` — drawable icon to show at the start of the chip.
`app:chipIconSize` — size of the chip icon.

```
chip.setOnClickListener {
   // Handle chip click
}
```

close icon

`app:closeIconVisible` — visibility of the close icon.
`app:closeIcon` — drawable icon show at end of the chip.
`app:closeIconSize` — size of the close icon.

```
chip.setOnCloseIconClickListener {
    // Handle chip close icon click
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the `closeIcon` properties since it already on the right side of the chip. something like this:

```
 <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
        android:id="@+id/customerListChipSort"
        style="@style/MyChip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sort"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:closeIcon="@drawable/ic_dropdown"
        app:closeIconEnabled="true"
        app:closeIconSize="@dimen/dimens_12dp"
        app:closeIconTint="@color/observatory_green" />
```

and the results is this: [image: sort button]